# Change Resource Group in Azure DevOps Starter

Tags: azure, devops

I have configured Azure DevOps Starter. But I had to change resource group for sql server and App Service. Now everything works good (with the new resource group) but section Azure resources (right pane) shows error:

"Azure Resources are unavailable"

[image]

How can I modify this section to show my new resources?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a view where it shows the default created resource groups. If you have moved them to new resource group unfortunately it won't appear here.

Comment: I hoped that azure stores somewhere a definiton of the DevOps starter and we could edit it